# Mp4 virus scanners

Tags: malware, antimalware, video

I used to download a lot of mp4's from untrusted sources. But I discovered that they could contain malware. I would like to know if there are any methods to clean or to check video files for malware.

Answer (score 2):

MP4 files are not executable files. This means that they are unable to execute malicious code directly. That being said, it is possible for the program that decodes/plays the file to have a vulnerability that the mp4 file could exploit. The threat that a video file poses to your system is much less than the threat a downloaded program poses to your system.

Your best bet for avoiding malicious mp4 files is using up to date software when decoding/playing these files. You can also use a throwaway virtual machine to view these files. Antivirus software would also most likely help prevent infection through this method.