# Is it possible for media files (mp3,mp4) contain malware

Tags: malware, virus

I would like to know the technique and if it’s possible in the first one place, not activating the media player the file it self

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Virus Encoded in Video](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18086/virus-encoded-in-video), [Is it possible to transfer a virus through browser video?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/122099/is-it-possible-to-transfer-a-virus-through-browser-video), [How to check if an mp4 file contains malware?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/227060/how-to-check-if-an-mp4-file-contains-malware), [Mp4 virus scanners](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/258723/mp4-virus-scanners)

Comment: Yes. Not necessarily because the files themselves are "executed", but the fact that it is data and programs that load data can be exploited. It is basically saying "Can data contain malware?" The answer is "Yes." It is a matter of how you load the data.

Comment: Is it possible? Of course. Can video have malware that executes without a media player opening the file? How, then, are you executing the malware? Malware isn't alive. It needs to be run by *something*.