# How can I check for malware embedded in an MP4 video?

Tags: spyware, virus-removal, video

How can I check for malware embedded in an MP4 video? It was sent over WhatsApp and I have played the video on my Android phone.

Norton scan came back clean.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if an mp4 file contains malware?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/227060/how-to-check-if-an-mp4-file-contains-malware), [Mp4 virus scanners](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/258723/mp4-virus-scanners), [Virus Encoded in Video](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18086/virus-encoded-in-video).